# webflux constructs incorrect URL value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I want to make a POST request using Spring Webflux. I tried this:

Web client build:

```
public RestClient(String gatewayUrl, String token, String username, String password, SslContext sslContext) {
        this.token = token;
        this.gatewayUrl = gatewayUrl;
        WebClient.Builder builder = WebClient.builder().baseUrl(gatewayUrl);
        if (sslContext != null) {
            HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().secure(sslContextSpec -> sslContextSpec.sslContext(sslContext));
            ClientHttpConnector httpConnector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);
            builder.clientConnector(httpConnector);
        }
        if (username != null && password != null) {
            builder.filter(basicAuthentication(username, password));
        }
        client = builder.build();
    }


......

public class RestClientBuilder {
    private String token;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private URL gatewayUrl;
    private SslContextBuilder sslContextBuilder;

    public static RestClientBuilder builder() {
        return new RestClientBuilder();
    }

    public RestClientBuilder token(String token) {
        this.token = validateAndTrim(token, "Token");
        return this;
    }

    public RestClientBuilder usernamePassword(String username, String password) {
        this.username = validateAndTrim(username, "Username");
        this.password = validateAndTrim(password, "Password");
        return this;
    }

    private String validateAndTrim(String value, final String parameter) {
        if (value == null || value.trim().isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(parameter + " is empty");
        }
        return value.trim();
    }

    public RestClientBuilder gatewayUrl(String gatewayUrl) {
        String urlSt = validateAndTrim(gatewayUrl, "Gateway URL");
        try {
            this.gatewayUrl = new URL(urlSt);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Malformed URL: " + urlSt, e);
        }
        return this;
    }

    public RestClientBuilder truststore(File truststoreFile) {
        getSslContextBuilder().trustManager(truststoreFile);
        return this;
    }

    public RestClientBuilder sslCertificate(File keyCertChainFile, File keyFile, String keyPassword) {
        getSslContextBuilder().keyManager(keyCertChainFile, keyFile, keyPassword);
        return this;
    }

    public RestClient build() throws SSLException {
        SslContext sslContext = sslContextBuilder != null ? sslContextBuilder.build() : null;
        return new RestClient(gatewayUrl.toString(), token, username, password, sslContext);
    }

    private SslContextBuilder getSslContextBuilder() {
        if (sslContextBuilder == null) {
            sslContextBuilder = SslContextBuilder.forClient();
        }
        return sslContextBuilder;
    }

}
```

Successful test:

```
        client.post()
            .uri("https://test.oppwa.com/v1/checkouts?entityId=1234567&amount=92.00&currency=GBP&paymentType=DB")
            .header(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, "Mozilla/5.0")
            .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer 11111111")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(SaleResponse.class);
```

Failed request:

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        map.add("entityId", "1234567");
        map.add("amount", "92.00");
        map.add("currency", "GBP");
        map.add("paymentType", "DB");

            client.post()
                .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("https://test.oppwa.com/v1/checkouts")
                        .queryParams(map)
                        .build())
                .header(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, "Mozilla/5.0")
                .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer 11111111")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(SaleResponse.class);
```

For some reason Webflux constructs this value:

```
.WebClientResponseException$NotFound: 404 Not Found from POST https://test.oppwa.com/v1/checkoutshttps:/test.oppwa.com/v1/checkouts?entityId=1234567&amount=92.00&currency=GBP&paymentType=DB
```

Do you know why the url link is 2 times repeated? How I can solve this issue?

Comment: Where are you getting `uriBuilder` from (you are aware that in the first snippet you're entirely discarding the result of using it?)?

Comment: uriBuilder is a Java Lambda expression.

Comment: Does the client have a base path set?

Comment: I made a mistake. post is updated.

Comment: I don't have a configuration for base path.

Comment: Show where you're constructing the client.

Comment: Also try putting `System.err.println(uriBuilder.toUriString())` in your lambda to see what it produces without any additional input from you.

Comment: Post updated with webclient configuration.

Comment: "I don't have a configuration for base path." →`WebClient.builder().baseUrl(gatewayUrl);`

Comment: oh... my mistake....

Comment: Do you know how I can set `gatewayUrl` to be configured here `uriBuilder.path(....)` as the url value?

Comment: Just don't add more `path`.

Comment: Yes this is one way but I want to override the url value if it's possible. Any other solution?

Comment: What you're trying to do is extremely unclear, and the solution ought to be simple in any case: Move your variables around to wherever you want them to be applied.

Answer (score 1):

You are building a RestClient with a gateway base url:

```
WebClient.Builder builder = WebClient.builder().baseUrl(gatewayUrl);
```

In the spring documentation you can read the following for `baseUrl`:

> The DefaultUriBuilderFactory is used to prepare the URL for every request with the given base URL, **unless the URL request for a given URL is absolute in which case the base URL is ignored.**

[WebClient.builder#baseUrl](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.Builder.html#baseUrl-java.lang.String-)

In your examples:

```
// Here you are supplying a an absolute url, which means base url is ignored
client.post()
      .uri("https://test.oppwa.com/v1/checkouts?entityId=1234567&amount=92.00&currency=GBP&paymentType=DB"
```

While in your other example:

```
client.post()
      // Here you are supplying only a path
      .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("https://test.oppwa.com/v1/checkouts")
                            .queryParams(map)
                            .build())
```

and for the documentation for path it says:

> Append to the path of this builder.
> The given value is appended as-is without any checks for slashes other than to clean up duplicates.

If you need to change the base url, i suggest you put the urls in property-files, and load them on startup instead. So depending on what env (dev, test, prod) you load a different profile with its own config and set that as the baseUrl. Then using a UrlBuilder you append the different paths on top.

[UriBuilder#Path](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriBuilder.html#path-java.lang.String-)